# why select * from return only the first field?

Tags: php, sql, fetch

I'm making the next query to the db

```
$result = $con->query ( 'select * from table');
$datos = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "Cantidad de datos: ".count($datos).",";
print_r($datos);
```

Should show an array with all the entries, but only show the first entry. Why?

PS: i saw other posts but i haven't limit or joins.

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` only return single array.

Comment: You are only fetching the first record when you do `$datos = $result->fetch_assoc();`.

Comment: Maybe `fetch_array`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> fetch_assoc fetches a result row as an associative array

So you could go through all the rows with a while cycle that fetches another row if possible.

```
$count = 0;
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    // You can access data like this -->> $row['data'];
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

and after you are done, you should free your memory associated with the result

```
$result->free();
```

But if you'd like to get count only, you could use mysql_num_rows that returns number of rows from result set.

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
```

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps explain why.

Comment: Added a little explanation, hope that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch_assoc` returns only one row when you are doing`$datos = $result->fetch_assoc();` You can fetch the entire array in both `PDO` and `mysqli`, Here is a example to fetch all rows using the [mysqli->fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function, hope this helps!

```
//Database Connection
$sqlConn =  new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

//Build SQL String
$sqlString = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

//Execute the query and put data into a result
$result = $this->sqlConn->query($sqlString);

//Copy result into a associative array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Copy result into a numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);

//Copy result into both a associative and numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please always refer to the manual of the framework you are using.  fetch_assoc();Fetches a result row as an associative array. If you want to fetch all the rows, use a while statement like so:

```
    $result = $c->query('SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf("'%s'@'%s'\n", $row['user'], $row['host']);
```